# Mismatched Vector Sizes: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (99,) - need help checking array syntax/operations

Tags: python, arrays, syntax, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am attempting to calculate the following five-point symmetric scheme for the diffusion equation (temperature diffusing through a rod with end points having temp = 100 degrees C).

This is the formula for the interior points:
[five-point symmetric scheme for interior points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBBqT.jpg)
and this is the formula for j=2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huhbW.png)

I am trying to create a function in Python that allows me to solve this scheme, but I am having problems with array sizes not lining up and I'm not sure why.

I already had a scheme working for the FTCS scheme where I just copied the syntax. Where I could have gone wrong is in my array syntax (still new to Python), i.e. taking T[:2] for j-1 and turning that into T[:3] for j-2.

Here is my entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Set parameters.
L = 1.0  # length of the rod (m)
nx = 101  # number of locations on the rod to run simulation
dx = L / (nx - 1)  # distance between two consecutive locations
alpha = 0.01e-4  #  thermal diffusivity of the rod (m^2/s)
nt = 2500  # number of time steps to compute
s = 0.1 # stability parameter
# Define the locations along the rod.
x = np.linspace(0.0, L, num=nx)

# Set the initial temperature along the rod.
T0 = np.zeros(nx)
T0[0] = 100.0 #(degrees C)
T0[-1] = T_end = 100.0 #(degrees C)

def five_point(T0, nt, s, dx):
    '''
    Computes and returns the temperature along the rod
    after a provided number of time steps,
    given the initial temperature and thermal diffusivity.
    Uses five_point computation scheme.
    
    Parameters:
    T0 : The initial temperature along the rod.
    nt : The number of time steps to compute.
    s: parameter that determines stability
    dx : The distance between two consecutive locations.
  
    Returns:
    T : The temperature along the rod.
    '''
    T = T0.copy()
    dt = s * dx**2 / alpha
    for n in range(nt):
        #for j=2:
        T[2] = (((11 * T[:2] /12) - (5 * T[1:-1] / 3) + (0.5 * T[2:]) + (T[3:] / 3) + (T[4:] / 12)) / (dx ** 2))
        #for interior points:
        T[2:-1] = (((-T[:3] / 12) + (4 * T[:2] / 3) - (2.5 * T[1:-1]) + (4 * T[2:] / 3) - (T[3:] / 12)) / (dx ** 2))
    return T

T_five_point = five_point(T0, nt, s, dx)
```

I get the errror: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (99,) pointing to the first line of code after the for loop, and I'm guessing there is a problem with T[2] not being registered as the third index in the array? Not sure, I am super new to Python so this error is throwing me for a loop (no pun intended).

Comment: Yes, your observation is correct, you can not add or assign slices of arrays of different length. What formulas are you trying to implement, what about T[1] and T[-1]?

Comment: I think that I need one for T[3], one for T[-2:2] and one for T[-1:1]

Comment: You should read again on the slicing logic and the "abbreviations" with negative numbers. `T[-1]` is the last element, `T[1:-1]` is the array shortened by the first and last element. `T[1:-1]` is compatible with `T[:-2]` and `T[2:]`. In the same way `T[2:-2]` is compatible with `T[:-4]`, `T[1:-3]`, `T[3:-1]` and `T[:-4]`. // `T[-2:2]` does not exist, but you can have the reverse sequence `T[-2:2:-1]` which is the sequence `T[-2], T[-3],..., T[4], T[3]`.